# HSQLDB v.2.3.0: USING predicate working as intended?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

The following query when executed against snapshot 50 of HSQLDB 2.3.0 produces an error.  The error message is "Error: duplicate column name in derived table: INST_ID"

```
SELECT c.lastname, to_date_string(c.dob), i.itag|| ': ' || 
       m.mrn, to_date_string(en.dofs), 
       to_date_string(en.dols), pa.payertag, 
       y.dxname, d.icd9, d.icd10, d.icd10name, 
       to_datetime_string(s.dos), r.cpt, r.rxname, p.lastname || ', ' || 
       p.firstname

FROM   Encounters AS en
       INNER JOIN Clients AS c USING ( cli_id )
       INNER JOIN Client_MRNs AS m ON c.defmrn_id = m.mrn_id
       INNER JOIN Institutions AS i USING ( inst_id )
       INNER JOIN Payers AS pa USING ( payer_id )

       INNER JOIN Encounter_DXs AS x USING ( enc_id )
       INNER JOIN Diagnoses AS d USING ( dx_id )
       INNER JOIN DXSynonyms AS y ON d.defsyn_id = y.syn_id

       INNER JOIN Services AS s USING ( enc_id )
       INNER JOIN RXCodes AS r USING ( rx_id )
       INNER JOIN Providers AS p USING ( prov_id )

WHERE  (s.dos >= 56453 AND s.dos < 56461)
ORDER BY c.lastname, en.dofs, s.dos;
```

However, when I execute the same query but replace all the USING predicates with ON ... = phrases it executes successfully:

```
SELECT c.lastname, to_date_string(c.dob), i.itag|| ': ' || 
       m.mrn, to_date_string(en.dofs), 
       to_date_string(en.dols), pa.payertag, 
       y.dxname, d.icd9, d.icd10, d.icd10name, 
       to_datetime_string(s.dos), r.cpt, r.rxname, p.lastname || ', ' || 
       p.firstname

FROM   Encounters AS en
       INNER JOIN Clients AS c ON c.cli_id = en.cli_id 
       INNER JOIN Client_MRNs AS m ON c.defmrn_id = m.mrn_id
       INNER JOIN Institutions AS i ON i.inst_id = m.inst_id
       INNER JOIN Payers AS pa ON pa.payer_id = en.payer_id

       INNER JOIN Encounter_DXs AS x ON x.enc_id = en.enc_id
       INNER JOIN Diagnoses AS d ON d.dx_id = x.dx_id
       INNER JOIN DXSynonyms AS y ON d.defsyn_id = y.syn_id

       INNER JOIN Services AS s ON s.enc_id = en.enc_id
       INNER JOIN RXCodes AS r ON r.rx_id = s.rx_id
       INNER JOIN Providers AS p ON p.prov_id = s.prov_id

WHERE  (s.dos >= 56453 AND s.dos < 56461)
ORDER BY c.lastname, en.dofs, s.dos;
```

Is this working as intended?  I like using USING because it results in less verbose, cleaner code.  I won't include the DDL for the tables right now (but can), because the queries are big and involve many tables, but there are three tables that have INST_ID fields.  One table has it as the primary key, and the other two have foreign keys to it.  Really the only difference in the queries is "ON" vs "USING".

Comment: Please list the table names that have INST_ID.

Comment: @fredt: Certainly.  The three tables in this query with INST_ID references or keys are INSTITUTIONS, CLIENT_MRNS, and ENCOUNTERS.  These tables have constraints involving INST_ID.  INSTITUTIONS has it as primary key.  CLIENT_MRNS has a foreign key and a composite unique constraint involving (INST_ID).  ENCOUNTERS has a foreign key constraint on it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first join, there is one INST_ID from ENCOUNTERS. After the second join, there is an additional one from CLIENTS_MRNS. The third join fails because of this duplication.

Comment: So, working as intended, then.  I had imagined that the inst_id's would still be distinguished by their fully qualified names and, therefore, not duplicates.  If there was a problem, I had figured it would be because of the lack of a qualified name for the inst_id resulting from USING ( inst_id ).

Comment: Ah ... so the DBMS can't figure out which inst_id to use with i.inst_id in the INNER JOIN Institutions AS i USING ( inst_id ).  At that point, the data set will include both m.inst_id and en.inst_id.